# Opening transformation in PDI from another version renders blank screen

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I'm trying to use Spoon 7.1 (a.k.a. Kettle, PDI, Pentaho Data Integration) to open transformations and jobs exported from a previous version (3.2.0).

However, if I try to either import, drag and drop or open the file, I end up with a new tab and a blank screen.

Looking at the log file, I found the following lines:

```
[Fatal Error] :55:26: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
2017/10/30 09:47:17 - org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.SpoonPerspectiveManager@588cd519 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Perspective with schedulerPerspective is not found.
```

I'm not sure of what to do, since the files were exported directly from Spoon's previous version.

I'll analyze the XML and see if anything looks strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out Spoon 3.2.0 doesn't include the XML prolog with the encoding, so Spoon doesn't know how to read it.

I included the following as the first line of every file and the transformations/jobs opened fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

That was OK in my case, because my file used `ISO-8859-1`, might need to be adjusted depending on the encoding of each situation.

This page helped me find out what encoding my file was using: [Chared](https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/)